# creating a flexible django data model with dynamic number of foreign key entries

Tags: django, django-models

I have trouble writing a django data model which can link multiple objects of the same type back to a single data entry. Here's are my current models:

```
class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True) 

class Config(models.Model)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   nbr_houses = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   houses = models.ManyToManyField(House) # this does not work, since I can only map a house once back to Config.
```

I wanna do the following (pseudo-code):

```
# define a new config and enforce that is should have houses.
$ a = Config(name = 'new_config', nbr_houses = 3)
# associate individual houses with this config
$ a.houses[0] = House(pk= 1)
# associate the same house a second time with this config
$ a.houses[1] = House(pk= 1)
# associate a third house to config.
$ a.houses[2] = House(pk= 2)
```

I create a new `Config` object `new_config` and say that this configuration should have 3 houses. My model should then automatically check and force me to link the correct number of houses back to `Config`. Additionally, a `House` might reference back twice to the same configuration.

I was thinking of writing `Config` the following way

```
class Config(models.Model)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   nbr_houses = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   houses = models.ManyToManyField(House, related_name='house0')
   houses1 = models.ManyToManyField(House, related_name='house1')
   houses2 = models.ManyToManyField(House, related_name='house2')
   houses3 = models.ManyToManyField(House, related_name='house3')
```

to basically reflect the maximum number of associations possible, but that's kinda inflexible. What's a better way of accomplishing this?

**EDIT:** Imagine the following use case:
You want to write a computer game where you can define a complexity of a scene. Each scene is saved into a `Config`. Per scene, I can place `x` many houses. Houses don't differ, they are just templates. So a scene could be made of 10 red houses, 2 blue houses and 1 yellow house. So for each `Config` entry I want to able to associate a different amount of houses (objects). Maybe later there will also be horses :) I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question was updated to explain that you potentially want to associate *some number* of each house with the config. In order to do this in Django you need a new model, that Django calls a [*intermediate model*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany). Like this:

```
class ConfigHouses(model.Model):
    config = model.ForeignKey('Config')
    house = model.ForeignKey('House')
    count = model.PositiveIntegerField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('config', 'house')
```

and then in the `Config` class you declare a `ManyToManyField` and assign the intermediate model to the `through` parameter:

```
class Config(model.Model):
    # ...
    houses = model.ManyToManyField('House', through = 'ConfigHouses')
```

To add houses to a config you create new instances of the intermediate model:

```
# Level 1 contains 4 red houses and 5 yellow houses
c = Config.objects.get_or_create(name = 'level-1')

red = House.objects.get_or_create(name = 'red')
ch = ConfigHouses(config = c, house = red, count = 4)
ch.save()

yellow = House.objects.get_or_create(name = 'yellow')
ch = ConfigHouses(config = c, house = yellow, count = 5)
ch.save()
```

After executing the above queries, the database will look something like this:

```
CONFIG TABLE
----------------
| pk | name    |
|----|---------|
|  1 | level-1 |
----------------

HOUSE TABLE
----------------
| pk | name    |
|----|---------|
|  1 | red     |
|  2 | yellow  |
----------------

CONFIGHOUSES TABLE
-------------------------------
| pk | config | house | count |
|----|--------|-------|-------|
|  1 |      1 |     1 |     4 |
|  2 |      1 |     2 |     5 |
-------------------------------
```

To find out how many houses of a particular type there are in a particular config, you query the intermediate table, either directly, or via either one of the models:

```
>>> ConfigHouses.objects.get(config = c, house__name = 'red').count
4
>>> c.confighouses.get(house__name = 'red').count
4
>>> yellow.confighouses_set.get(config = c).count
5
```

---

#### Original answer

(The original question did not make it clear that the many-to-many relation needed multiplicity, but I'm leaving the original answer in place in case it's useful.)

Your original idea (that `houses` should be a `ManyToManyField`) is the right idea. It's just that in order to refer to the `House` class before you define it, you need to pass the *name* of the class. See [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself.

It's also bad idea to have a `nbr_houses` field because it could become incorrect if someone updates the many-to-many relation without also remembering to update the `nbr_houses` field. You can use `houses.count()` to get the number of related houses.

So your `Config` class should look like this:

```
class Config(models.Model)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   # The class House is not yet defined, so refer to it by name.
   houses = models.ManyToManyField('House')
```

And you can update the many-to-many relation using the [RelatedManager interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove): there are methods `add`, `create`, `remove`, `clear`, or you can just assign to it:

```
config.houses = House.objects.filter(color = 'red')
```

Comment: the reason for `nbr_houses` to be a separate field, is that this should force the user to associate as many houses with the config as are defined in `nbr_houses`. With the `models.ManyToManyField('House')` setting, I can only select each house once. But I want to associate some houses maybe multiple times.

Comment: great! can you expand you answer and show me how I can create a config with 4 red and 5 yellow houses. right now it seems to me like a config can only consists of x houses of color y, but not a mixed amount of colors and number per color. thanks!!

Comment: ah, so basically two `ConfigHouses` instances will be mapped back to `c`, correct?

Comment: I added a diagram showing the contents of the database after executing the queries in the example.

Comment: awesome! If the ordering of the houses would matter (let's say 2 red houses first, then 1 yellow, then 1 red, then 2 yellow), would you use the same model, and add `ConfigHouses` sequentially? or would you use a different model? Thanks!

Comment: The length of this comment thread suggests that it's probably time to close out this question and open a new one, but briefly: if the order matters, then you need to modify the `ConfigHouses` intermediate model accordingly (perhaps by adding an `order` field).